# Note sounds off - Beginning-Intermediate Piano player

Tags: piano, digital-piano

I started teaching myself piano and am currently trying to learn "Carlos Gardell - Por Una Cabeza" (https://www.8notes.com/scores/18093.asp). I'm advancing fine, however there are two notes in the piece that just sound off:

[image: I interpret this note as: C sharp + B flat + F sharp + D. When I play this note, it just doesn't sound quite like in the real piece.]

[image: This one is B flat for me. However it doesn't sound good, when I play it, sounds off.]

First picture: I interpret this note as: C sharp + B flat + F sharp + D. When I play it, it just doesn't sound quite like in the real piece.

Second picture: This one is B flat for me. However, it doesn't sound good when I play it, it sounds off.

Do I interpret the notes correctly? Might it only sound off because I haven't managed to play the song with a good speed yet? The rest of the notes sound very nice when I play them. I am playing on a Yahama E413 and have the mode "Grand Piano" selected.

Thanks for any help.

Leonore

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention that the bass cleff has to sharps on the first one:

Is it still, as you replied, C natural? Or ist it C sharp in this case?

Foto attached:
[image]

**EDIT NR.2:**

Here is the entire piece, up to the point that I am struggling with:

[image]

That's how I understood it now from all the comments: The two sharp signs next to the bass clef determine that all Cs and Fs in the same line are played sharp. However, in the chord that I am struggling with, the first C has a natural sign, which determines, if not indicated otherwise in the next C of the same chord by a flat or sharp sign, that all other Cs in the same chord will be played natural as well.

Comment: Interesting that your music's chord symbol uses D7**(♯5)** but writes in a **B♭**.

Comment: The way I understand it, D7#5 would be C+ A sharp + F sharp + D, the chord expresses C+ B flat + F sharp + D, which I guess does not make a difference for me right now. However, since the bass clef has two sharps in the beginning, should the C be played C natural or C sharp? Also, feel free to look at the song at: https://www.8notes.com/scores/18093.asp. In my opinion, D7#5, either with C sharp or C natural, doesn't sound right there

Comment: As @JETM said in the answer, it's difficult to say something without context. Indeed by playing these bars alone, it sounds odd. Could you provide the whole passage, at least one bar before and one after? I think it's more likely you get the answer you're looking for!

Comment: I just added a second edit and also attached a picture with more context. I hope I'm reasoning correctly. It actually sounds better playing C+A sharp + F sharp + D, instead of C sharp+A sharp + F sharp + D

Comment: Re: last edit: Not quite. Accidentals like that natural sign are good until the end of the measure. If there were a C in measure 13, it would be sharp.

Comment: I think I'm still confused by the terminology sometimes, but I'm catching up. So the two sharp signs next to the bass clef indicate "Cs and Fs sharp" but in measure 12 (seperated from measure 11 & 13 by the vertical lines), the first C has a natural sign, which means I have to play it C natural. The natural sign on the first C of measure 12 determines also that the second C in the measure has to be played C natural (unless it had a flat or sharp sign) as well.

Comment: @Leonore - Yep. It's a C natural.

Answer (score 2):

Accidentals such as naturals continue for the rest of the measure. Therefore, the chord in the first measure should have C natural, not C sharp.

Seeing the second measure in isolation, a B natural instead of Bb would be the obvious "vanilla" thing to do. So it is right that it sounds off to you for now.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I edited my question a little bit (edit at the bottom). Still C natural or C sharp then?

Comment: @Leonore Natural because of the natural sign on the previous chord.

Comment: The second measure starts with a D7 (D-F#-A-C with an A-natural) then a D7#5 (D-F#-A#-C with an A#) which doesn't resolve down, it chromatically leads up to the next chord, the G.